# Raspberry BLE peripherals alternative to bleno

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, peripherals, bleno

Until now I have developed several programs to use in my Raspberry Rpi2 and RPi3 as BLE perifpherals using [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno).
Can anyone tell me if there is something alternative to Bleno, in Python or even better in C, to develop a code for a BLE peripherals service for my Raspberry?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this same pain as you - trying to get a good BLE Peripheral role library for python - so I went ahead and ported Bleno to python2/3.
It's still a WIP, but the Echo demo works just fine.

https://github.com/Adam-Langley/pybleno/

And it's on pypi as "pybleno"

Of course, a big shout out to Sandeep Mistry for the fantastic original node codebase.

Hopefully people find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always use the HCI_CHANNEL_USER feature in Linux to talk to the Bluetooth controller directly (from C for example). In fact that's exactly what bleno does. Just follow the HCI protocol in the Bluetooth specification.

Comment: Can you give some more details on that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you answers for C, but [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) seems to be the best in breed for speaking to BLE peripherals (as bleno does) right now, and if you want to use core mode, there's Adafruit's [BlueFruit LE](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE).

Caveat: I'm only getting my feet wet with Pi peripherals myself and don't have any successful projects with either of these yet.

Comment: You’re confusing Bleno with Noble. Noble implements BLE central device ”for spraking to BLE peripherals”, while Bleno implements peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a library written in C as far as I know, but here's an interesting place to start:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/ (especially interesting are: doc/mgmt-api.txt, doc/gatt-api.txt for LE things)

There seem to be two interfaces to do Bluetooth stuff: D-Bus and HCI sockets.
HCI sockets are actual C socket()s with the special AF_BLUETOOTH domain (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html is kind of helpful for explaining this).
And you can use org.bluez.* for higher-level interfacing using D-Bus.

Getting all of that to work would be probably a nightmare, and all of the other Python libraries probably work fine. If you want higher performance, you could totally get something to work in C or Rust, and all you should need is sockets and D-Bus, it just sounds really really hard.